# Polymer event on-content-scroll not firing

Tags: polymer, iron-list

I have an `iron-list` which I add new items to while scrolling to the bottom using `iron-scroll-threshold`. That works fine.

What I also need is a general event which is fired when scrolling stops.

I need that to know whether the listed items (m.message) have been *seen* by the user, by checking which items are currently visible in the view-port after scrolling, and then marking them as "read".

```
<div class="container" on-content-scroll="_scrollHandler">
    <iron-scroll-threshold id="threshold" scroll-target="mlist" lower-threshold="500" on-lower-threshold="_loadMoreData"></iron-scroll-threshold>
    <iron-list items="[[messages]]" id="mlist" as="m">
        <template>
            <div>
                <p>[[m.message]]</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
</div>
```

The handler `_scrollHandler` is never fired however.

What would be necessary to get an event after scrolling ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works at the end by moving `on-scroll="_scrollHandler"` to the `iron-list`:

```
<div class="container">
    <iron-scroll-threshold id="threshold" scroll-target="mlist" lower-threshold="500" on-lower-threshold="_loadMoreData"></iron-scroll-threshold>
    <iron-list items="[[messages]]" id="mlist" as="m" on-scroll="_scrollHandler">
        <template>
            <div>
                <p>[[m.message]]</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
</div>
```

With the function being:

```
_scrollHandler: function() {
    this.debounce("markAsRead", function(e) {
        console.log("debounce");
    }, 500);
}
```

**Edit:**

In case the `iron-scroll-threshold` wraps the `iron-list`, you need to move `on-scroll` to the `iron-scroll-threshold`-element:

```
<iron-scroll-threshold on-scroll="_scrollHandler" id="threshold" on-lower-threshold="_loadMore">
    <iron-list scroll-target="threshold">...</iron-list>
</iron-scroll-threshold>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the style: `overflow: auto` on the `div.container`. This will make sure the scroll event will invoke.

I could not find any such event as `content-scroll`, but with the changes above you should be able to change your *HTML*  to bind against the handler like: `on-scroll="_scrollHandler"`.

To detect if scrolling has stopped, I'd recommend using [***Polymer.debounce***](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-debounce) to have the callback set the `isScrolling` state to false like:

```
app._scrollHandler = function (e) {
    app.isScrolling = true
    app.debounce('scroll-handler', _ => {
        app.isScrolling = false
    }, 20)
}
```

Comment: I put your suggested changes in place, but unfortunately it does still not work. Maybe there is an interaction with the iron-list and/or iron-scroll-threshold?

Comment: It seems you've answered your question... In any case, please make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out! I can optionally edit my answer to include your corrected solution.